# Pattern-matching: query returns 'no' even when base case provided

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

I have a simple Prolog-program that I need some help debugging.
The point is to extend the program by pattern-matching to create a proof checker for propositional logic. The problem I have is that I get no when I expect yes and my 'fix' (providing a base case for valid_proof_aux) still gives me two solutions and I don't know why.

Not sure how to go about debugging Prolog yet, sorry.

```
%call:
valid_proof([p],p,[[1, p, premise]])

%src:

reverse_it([],Z,Z).

reverse_it([H|T],Z,Acc) :- reverse_it(T,Z,[H|Acc]).


valid_proof(Prems,Goal,Proof):-
    last(Proof, [_, Goal, _]),
    reverse_it(Proof, RevP, []),
    valid_proof_aux(Prems, RevP) .

valid_proof_aux(Prems,
        [[_,Prop,premise] | T]):-
    memberchk(Prop,Prems),
    valid_proof_aux(Prems,T).

%my 'fix'
valid_proof_aux(_, []) :- true .
```

Comment: Does your program, as you have shown it, actually compile without any warnings or errors? If it does not, what are the warning or error you see? (You should never ignore warnings, they almost invariably show that you have a real problem with your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really show how to run the program and what exactly you get (you should edit your question with and add this), so this answer is a bit of a guess, but anyway:

You need the base case either way (as you observe yourself), `valid_proof_aux/2` would fail when the list becomes empty `[]` and does not match `[[...]|T]` anymore.

```
?- [] = [_|_]. % try to unify an empty list with a non-empty list
false.
```

What you need to do to get rid of the choice point is to put the list argument as the first argument.

```
valid_proof_aux([], _).
valid_proof_aux([[_,Prop,premise]|T], Prems) :-
    memberchk(Prop, Prems),
    valid_proof_aux(T, Prems).
```

Note that you don't need the `:- true.`, this is implicit. Also, avoid leaving any blanks on the two sides of the `|` in `[Head|Tail]`.

Comment: You forgot to switch to valid_proof_aux(T,Prems) :)!

Comment: @ejbs I did initially indeed but now I see it correct?

Comment: One question: Why does Prolog give me a 'true?' prompt when I run my program?

Comment: @ejbs Which implementation are you using? And you should really include the exact contents of your interaction with the Prolog interpreter in your question so that it is easier for others to know what you are actually dealing with.

Comment: Sorry Boris, I'm using gprolog. See original Q
I press enter when I am prompted 'true ?'

Comment: Yes, it does. Hm, the prompt disappeared on recompilation. Thank you.